PC in and out standby mode when mobile is connected
When I connect my mobile via USB to my Win11 PC, it goes to standby after 10min of inactivity as normal. However, after 10s the PC automatically starts itself up again.
This is just pure nonsense. How can it be stopped?
PS: It doesn't seem to matter wheter selective USB energy saving is disabled or not.

Ah, this answer from https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/tbze6h/how_do_you_fix_your_desktop_pc_from_waking_itself/ helped me out already
